# Displaying graphs/charts in Django

Tags: python, django, charts

I'm making a report app in Django that involves plenty of graphs and charts.

Is there an easy graphing library/module that allows me to achieve this workflow:

1. Execute my SQL queries
2. Parse the returned data to the graphing library/module
3. Graphing library/module manipulates the data into a chart/graph which I can output to a Django template easily.

I've spent the last couple of days playing around with Matplotlib and Django. There are seemingly only a few ways to get the graphs to render in Django.

1. Use 2 views, one to render the PNG and the other one to output the HTML with the img src pointing to the first view. [Link](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/a574f3444c0bc85a/9b6952e009cba358#9b6952e009cba358)
2. [Data URI's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538715/plot-a-graph-in-the-html-file-using-django)
3. Write the image to file and then call it with the view

Is there anyway I can do this more easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to look at

[Django Graphos](https://github.com/agiliq/django-graphos)

It supports lot of backends, and integrates well with Django orm, but can work with other data sources too.

#### Chart types supported

Flot

- Line chart
- Bar Chart
- Point Chart

Google Charts

- Line chart
- Column chart
- Bar chart
- Candlestick charts
- Pie chart

YUI

- Line chart
- Column chart
- Bar chart
- Pie chart

Morris.js

- Line chart
- Column chart
- Donut chart

[Disclosure: I am one of the authors]

Comment: Graphos is in disrepair on GitHub. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

One lighter alternative is [pycha](https://pypi.org/project/pycha/)

See this blogpost to get an idea: [A quick post on using Python Charts to generate nice SVG charts for your django website](http://www.stuartaxon.com/2011/02/25/using-pycha-with-django)

Another option is to include [google charts](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-chart-tools)
in your templates.

If rendering the graph via js in your templates is an option, these
are two popular libraries:

- http://www.highcharts.com
- http://www.jqplot.com

Comment: The edit queue for this answer is full.
pycha is now at https://pypi.org/project/pycha/  Highcharts is commercial and jqplot hasn't been maintained since 2016. :(

Comment: pycha looks not updated since 2019.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at these well know libraries which will come handy to plot graphs without ever writing JS

| name | link | last updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chartit | https://github.com/chartit/django-chartit | 2018 |
| ChartJs | https://github.com/novafloss/django-chartjs | 2022 |
| Django charts | http://www.fusioncharts.com/django-charts/ |  |
| Django nvd3 | https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3 | 2020 |
| Django graphos | https://github.com/agiliq/django-graphos | 2017 |
| Django Gcharts | https://github.com/rhblind/django-gcharts | archived 2015 |

Answer (score 3):

All the Django modules for displaying graphs take a lot of configuration and setup. However I found one solution with only one dependency: plotly.

You can make all your plots in Python and export them into HTML format to include in your Django output.

Look at this article for an example: http://www.codingwithricky.com/2019/08/28/easy-django-plotly/