# can we implement charts like this with django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

[image: like]

There is any possible way we can apply chart like this in python using matplotlib if not can anyone guide me in proper direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do pie chart as well as stacked bar chart. You can find various examples in different sites. Below are some of them.

You might want to look at

1. http://django-chartit.mrsenko.com/demo/chart/basic-line/
2. ChartJs: https://github.com/novafloss/django-chartjs
3. Django charts: http://www.fusioncharts.com/django-charts/
4. Django nvd3: https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3
5. Django graphos: http://agiliq.com/demo/graphos/
6. Django Gcharts: https://github.com/rhblind/django-gcharts

Found it from - [Displaying graphs/charts in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631247/displaying-graphs-charts-in-django)

Comment: that was helpful do you know how can i put 47.59cr as a label at center of pie chart?

Comment: it depends on which library you are using, based on that you hv to check their documentation,

Answer (score 0):

You can use CanvasJS Django charts. It supports [doughnut chart](https://canvasjs.com/python-charts/python-pie-doughnut-charts/doughnut-chart-index-data-label/) & [stacked column 100% chart](https://canvasjs.com/python-charts/python-column-charts/stacked-column-100-chart/), as per your requirements. You can even customize the look & feel of the chart by changing the color, fonts, etc. to match it with your webpage.